# After Monterey 12.3.1 Update I couldnt run Flutter project on my Phone

Tags: android, flutter

I am using Monterey 12.3.1 version on my MAC. When I connect my phone to MAC. Than run the application on my phone I get:

```
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
```

But I dont find anywhere adb server, When I give this command:

```
where adb

/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

I checked /usr/bin/ and usr/local/ files but I couldnt find anywhere another adb server. How can I solve this problem ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the version in your  system using `adb version`. A simpler method can be to remove adb 41 and install adb 40

Comment: Android studio might have a different version, and you might have a different version. You will have to just remove them and maybe install 40 manually.

Comment: adb versoın command output is: Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 33.0.1-8253317
Installed as /Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb

Comment: But I install this adb on android studio package manager. How this is different version I dont understand ?

Comment: How can I downgrade my abd version, when I try to download on this linkhttps://github.com/awake558/adb-win related version of the adb 40, my mac doesnt give any permission run this adb